# Why lucene index stored in BerkeleyDB?

Tags: lucene

i found some tutorial they stored index file into BerkeleyDB instead of storing index file into directory. Why? Is it improve the searching performance?

Comment: As a proof of concept? Bored developer with free time? Could you give us the url to the tutorial?

Comment: Lucene in Action second edition [page no 307]

Answer (score 1):

The book mentioned, [Lucene in Action, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/hatcher3/), does mention Berkeley DB in chapter `9.2 Storing an index in Berkeley DB`. As mentioned, it introduces transactional support. A database commit will store both the newly changed entities, and any changes written to the database. The entities and the search index will always be synchronized.

It will, per definition, be slowed than pure disk writes since there's something more going on during writing. Same thing goes for reading; there will be some kind of penalty for storing the data in a custom format. However, the amount of data stored in a "personal information manager" may not be that large and a small penalty may not be noticed (background loading perhaps?) or is accepted for the transactional support provided by a database based solution.

Quotes from the book, page 292.

> The Chandler project (http://chandlerproject.org) is an ongoing effort to build an open source personal information manager. Chandler aims to manage diverse types of information such as email, instant messages, appointments, contacts, tasks, notes, web pages, blogs, bookmarks, photos, and much more. It’s an extensible platform, not just an application. Search is a crucial component to the Chandler infrastructure.
>   [...]
>   Chandler’s underlying repository uses Oracle’s Berkeley DB in a vastly different way than a traditional relational database, inspired by Resource Description Frame- work (RDF) and associative databases. Andi created a Lucene directory implementa- tion that uses Berkeley DB as the underlying storage mechanism. An interesting side effect of having a Lucene index in a database is the transactional support it provides. Andi donated his implementation to the Lucene project, and it’s maintained in the db/bdb area of the contrib directory.